# C Implementation of heapsort does not change the array

Tags: c, heapsort, binary-heap

I was implementing heapsort as an exercise with given binary heap APIs and did just fine. Then I tried to implement it from scratch and failed.
The algorithm should, given an array of size n, make it into a binary heap in place and with O(logN) complexity; then proceed to extract the root (max elem), place it at the end of the array and reset the heap-properties.
Anyway, it just does not work, I cannot figure out why. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define DEBUG_MODE 1
#define parent_index(i) (((i + 1) % 2)? ((i >>1)-1):(((i+1)>>1)-1) )
#define left_child_index(i) (((i + 1) << 1)-1)
#define right_child_index(i) (((i + 1) << 1))

#define is_higher(a, b) (((a) > (b))? (a) : (b))

#define HEAP_SORT_TEST_ARRAY_SIZE 10
#define HEAP_SORT_TEST_TEST_TIMES 8
#define is_odd(u) (u - ((u >> 1) << 1))

typedef int b_heap_entry;
typedef struct heap
{
    b_heap_entry* array;
    int capacity;
    int size;
} b_heap;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void array_print(int* array, unsigned size)
{
    unsigned u;
    printf("[");
    for(u = 0; u < size; u++)
        printf("%d, ", array[u]);
    printf("\b\b]\n");
}
#if DEBUG_MODE
                                                                                                        void heap_print(b_heap* h)
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                            printf("BINARY HEAP:\n(size %d)\n", h->size);
                                                                                                            unsigned u;
                                                                                                            for(u = 0; u <= h->size; u++)
                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                if(is_power2(u+1)) printf("\n");
                                                                                                                printf("<%d>    ", h->array[u]);
                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                            printf("\n");
                                                                                                        }
#endif
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int closest_lower_p2(int i)
{
    int n;
    for(n = 0; i >1; i = i >> 1)
        n++;
    return (1 << n);
}
#if DEBUG_MODE
                                                                                                        int is_power2(unsigned u)
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                            if(u == 1)
                                                                                                                return 0;
                                                                                                            for(; u > 1; u = u >> 1)
                                                                                                                if(is_odd(u)) return 0;
                                                                                                            return 1;
                                                                                                        }
#endif
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline void siftDown(b_heap* h, int i)
{
    int child_index;
    b_heap_entry tmp;
    while(left_child_index(i) <= h->size)
    {
        /*
         * child index is the index of the greater child
         */
        child_index = ((right_child_index(i) >= h->size)||
        (is_higher(h->array[left_child_index(i)], h->array[right_child_index(i)])))?
         left_child_index(i) : right_child_index(i);
        /*
         * if the node at index i is lesser than 1 of its children, we swap them, let i be the new 
         * parent index (child_index) and keep going until i is greater than both its children or 
         * there are no more children (i is now a leaf)
         */
        if(is_higher(h->array[i], h->array[child_index]))
            return;
        tmp = h->array[i];
        h->array[i] = h->array[child_index];
        h->array[child_index] = tmp;
        i = child_index;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
b_heap_entry heap_poll(b_heap* h) {
/*
 * First we find the last leaf and swap the root with it
 * (Since we can remove leaves without having to modify the
 * shape of the heap)
 */
    b_heap_entry root = h->array[0];
    h->array[0] = h->array[--(h->size)];
/*
 * Now we restore the order
 */
    siftDown(h, 0);
    return root;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
b_heap* array2heap(int * array, int size) 
{
#if DEBUG_MODE
                                                                                                            printf("Making the array\n");
                                                                                                            array_print(array, size);
                                                                                                            printf("into a binary heap\ndone...\n");
#endif
    b_heap* h = malloc(sizeof(b_heap));
    h->size = size;
    h->capacity = size;
    h->array = array;
    int i;
    for(i = closest_lower_p2(h->size) - 1; i >=0; i--)
        siftDown(h, i);
#if DEBUG_MODE
                                                                                                            heap_print(h);
                                                                                                            printf("done...\n");
#endif
    return h;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void heap_sort(int * array, int size) {
    b_heap* h = array2heap(array, size);
    while(size >= 1)
    {
        array[--size] = heap_poll(h);
    }
    free(h);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline void array_fill_with_rand(int* array, unsigned size)
{
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = rand();
}

int heap_sort_test()
{
    unsigned u, w;
    int array[HEAP_SORT_TEST_ARRAY_SIZE];
    for(u = 0; u < HEAP_SORT_TEST_TEST_TIMES; u++)
    {
        array_fill_with_rand(array, HEAP_SORT_TEST_ARRAY_SIZE);

#if DEBUG_MODE
                                                                                                            printf("Array n%d before sorting:\n", u);
                                                                                                            array_print(array, HEAP_SORT_TEST_ARRAY_SIZE);
#endif

        heap_sort(array, HEAP_SORT_TEST_ARRAY_SIZE);

#if DEBUG_MODE
                                                                                                            printf("Array n%d after sorting:\n", u);
                                                                                                            array_print(array, HEAP_SORT_TEST_ARRAY_SIZE);
#endif

        for(w = 0; w <  HEAP_SORT_TEST_ARRAY_SIZE - 1; w++)
            if(array[w] > array[w+1])
            {
                printf("Test n.%d failed...\n(%d is higher than %d)\nAbort...", u, array[w], array[w+1]);
                return 0;
            }
        printf("Test n.%d passed...\n", u);
    }
    printf("All test passed, nice job!\n");
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    heap_sort_test();
    return 1;
}
```

This is the output (I removed the "return 0" in heap_sort_test() to get more data, with it it blocks at the first try):

```
Array n0 before sorting:
[1804289383, 846930886, 1681692777, 1714636915, 1957747793, 424238335, 719885386, 1649760492, 596516649, 1189641421, ]
Making the array
[1804289383, 846930886, 1681692777, 1714636915, 1957747793, 424238335, 719885386, 1649760492, 596516649, 1189641421, ]
into a binary heap
done...
BINARY HEAP:
(size 10)
<1804289383>    
<846930886>    <1681692777>    
<1714636915>    <1957747793>    <424238335>    <719885386>    
<1649760492>    <596516649>    <1189641421>    <4195760>    
done...
Array n0 after sorting:
[846930886, 1681692777, 1714636915, 1957747793, 424238335, 719885386, 1649760492, 596516649, 1189641421, 1804289383, ]
Test n.0 failed...
(1957747793 is higher than 424238335)...
Test n.0 failed...
(1649760492 is higher than 596516649)...
Test n.0 passed...
Array n1 before sorting:
[1025202362, 1350490027, 783368690, 1102520059, 2044897763, 1967513926, 1365180540, 1540383426, 304089172, 1303455736, ]
Making the array
[1025202362, 1350490027, 783368690, 1102520059, 2044897763, 1967513926, 1365180540, 1540383426, 304089172, 1303455736, ]
into a binary heap
done...
BINARY HEAP:
(size 10)
<1025202362>    
<1350490027>    <783368690>    
<1102520059>    <2044897763>    <1967513926>    <1365180540>    
<1540383426>    <304089172>    <1303455736>    <4195760>    
done...
Array n1 after sorting:
[1350490027, 783368690, 1102520059, 2044897763, 1967513926, 1365180540, 1540383426, 304089172, 1303455736, 1025202362, ]
Test n.1 failed...
(1350490027 is higher than 783368690)...
Test n.1 failed...
(2044897763 is higher than 1967513926)...
Test n.1 failed...
(1967513926 is higher than 1365180540)...
Test n.1 failed...
(1540383426 is higher than 304089172)...
Test n.1 failed...
(1303455736 is higher than 1025202362)...
Test n.1 passed...
Array n2 before sorting:
[35005211, 521595368, 294702567, 1726956429, 336465782, 861021530, 278722862, 233665123, 2145174067, 468703135, ]
Making the array
[35005211, 521595368, 294702567, 1726956429, 336465782, 861021530, 278722862, 233665123, 2145174067, 468703135, ]
into a binary heap
done...
BINARY HEAP:
(size 10)
<35005211>    
<521595368>    <294702567>    
<1726956429>    <336465782>    <861021530>    <278722862>    
<233665123>    <2145174067>    <468703135>    <4195760>    
done...
Array n2 after sorting:
[521595368, 294702567, 1726956429, 336465782, 861021530, 278722862, 233665123, 2145174067, 468703135, 35005211, ]
Test n.2 failed...
(521595368 is higher than 294702567)...
Test n.2 failed...
(1726956429 is higher than 336465782)...
Test n.2 failed...
(861021530 is higher than 278722862)...
Test n.2 failed...
(278722862 is higher than 233665123)...
Test n.2 failed...
(2145174067 is higher than 468703135)...
Test n.2 failed...
(468703135 is higher than 35005211)...
Test n.2 passed...
Array n3 before sorting:
[1101513929, 1801979802, 1315634022, 635723058, 1369133069, 1125898167, 1059961393, 2089018456, 628175011, 1656478042, ]
Making the array
[1101513929, 1801979802, 1315634022, 635723058, 1369133069, 1125898167, 1059961393, 2089018456, 628175011, 1656478042, ]
into a binary heap
done...
BINARY HEAP:
(size 10)
<1101513929>    
<1801979802>    <1315634022>    
<635723058>    <1369133069>    <1125898167>    <1059961393>    
<2089018456>    <628175011>    <1656478042>    <4195760>    
done...
Array n3 after sorting:
[1801979802, 1315634022, 635723058, 1369133069, 1125898167, 1059961393, 2089018456, 628175011, 1656478042, 1101513929, ]
Test n.3 failed...
(1801979802 is higher than 1315634022)...
Test n.3 failed...
(1315634022 is higher than 635723058)...
Test n.3 failed...
(1369133069 is higher than 1125898167)...
Test n.3 failed...
(1125898167 is higher than 1059961393)...
Test n.3 failed...
(2089018456 is higher than 628175011)...
Test n.3 failed...
(1656478042 is higher than 1101513929)...
Test n.3 passed...
Array n4 before sorting:
[1131176229, 1653377373, 859484421, 1914544919, 608413784, 756898537, 1734575198, 1973594324, 149798315, 2038664370, ]
Making the array
[1131176229, 1653377373, 859484421, 1914544919, 608413784, 756898537, 1734575198, 1973594324, 149798315, 2038664370, ]
into a binary heap
done...
BINARY HEAP:
(size 10)
<1131176229>    
<1653377373>    <859484421>    
<1914544919>    <608413784>    <756898537>    <1734575198>    
<1973594324>    <149798315>    <2038664370>    <4195760>    
done...
Array n4 after sorting:
[1653377373, 859484421, 1914544919, 608413784, 756898537, 1734575198, 1973594324, 149798315, 2038664370, 1131176229, ]
Test n.4 failed...
(1653377373 is higher than 859484421)...
Test n.4 failed...
(1914544919 is higher than 608413784)...
Test n.4 failed...
(1973594324 is higher than 149798315)...
Test n.4 failed...
(2038664370 is higher than 1131176229)...
Test n.4 passed...
Array n5 before sorting:
[1129566413, 184803526, 412776091, 1424268980, 1911759956, 749241873, 137806862, 42999170, 982906996, 135497281, ]
Making the array
[1129566413, 184803526, 412776091, 1424268980, 1911759956, 749241873, 137806862, 42999170, 982906996, 135497281, ]
into a binary heap
done...
BINARY HEAP:
(size 10)
<1129566413>    
<184803526>    <412776091>    
<1424268980>    <1911759956>    <749241873>    <137806862>    
<42999170>    <982906996>    <135497281>    <4195760>    
done...
Array n5 after sorting:
[184803526, 412776091, 1424268980, 1911759956, 749241873, 137806862, 42999170, 982906996, 135497281, 1129566413, ]
Test n.5 failed...
(1911759956 is higher than 749241873)...
Test n.5 failed...
(749241873 is higher than 137806862)...
Test n.5 failed...
(137806862 is higher than 42999170)...
Test n.5 failed...
(982906996 is higher than 135497281)...
Test n.5 passed...
Array n6 before sorting:
[511702305, 2084420925, 1937477084, 1827336327, 572660336, 1159126505, 805750846, 1632621729, 1100661313, 1433925857, ]
Making the array
[511702305, 2084420925, 1937477084, 1827336327, 572660336, 1159126505, 805750846, 1632621729, 1100661313, 1433925857, ]
into a binary heap
done...
BINARY HEAP:
(size 10)
<511702305>    
<2084420925>    <1937477084>    
<1827336327>    <572660336>    <1159126505>    <805750846>    
<1632621729>    <1100661313>    <1433925857>    <4195760>    
done...
Array n6 after sorting:
[2084420925, 1937477084, 1827336327, 572660336, 1159126505, 805750846, 1632621729, 1100661313, 1433925857, 511702305, ]
Test n.6 failed...
(2084420925 is higher than 1937477084)...
Test n.6 failed...
(1937477084 is higher than 1827336327)...
Test n.6 failed...
(1827336327 is higher than 572660336)...
Test n.6 failed...
(1159126505 is higher than 805750846)...
Test n.6 failed...
(1632621729 is higher than 1100661313)...
Test n.6 failed...
(1433925857 is higher than 511702305)...
Test n.6 passed...
Array n7 before sorting:
[1141616124, 84353895, 939819582, 2001100545, 1998898814, 1548233367, 610515434, 1585990364, 1374344043, 760313750, ]
Making the array
[1141616124, 84353895, 939819582, 2001100545, 1998898814, 1548233367, 610515434, 1585990364, 1374344043, 760313750, ]
into a binary heap
done...
BINARY HEAP:
(size 10)
<1141616124>    
<84353895>    <939819582>    
<2001100545>    <1998898814>    <1548233367>    <610515434>    
<1585990364>    <1374344043>    <760313750>    <4195760>    
done...
Array n7 after sorting:
[84353895, 939819582, 2001100545, 1998898814, 1548233367, 610515434, 1585990364, 1374344043, 760313750, 1141616124, ]
Test n.7 failed...
(2001100545 is higher than 1998898814)...
Test n.7 failed...
(1998898814 is higher than 1548233367)...
Test n.7 failed...
(1548233367 is higher than 610515434)...
Test n.7 failed...
(1585990364 is higher than 1374344043)...
Test n.7 failed...
(1374344043 is higher than 760313750)...
Test n.7 passed...
All test passed, nice job!
```

Comment: the #ifdef DEBUG_MODE .... #endif should cut out the debug prints when I solve the problem (I am saying this since I do not know if it is common practice or even any good at all)

Comment: break it down into steps and try to narrow down your issue.  And step through the code in a debugger and inspect what is happening around where things start going wrong.

Comment: I do not know how to use a debugger other than basic memory allocs and frees with valgrind and segmentation faults analysis with gdb.

Comment: But it appears that array2heap() which should make the array into a heap, does nothing at all

Comment: Then this will be the perfect opportunity to learn how to use gdb.

Comment: How should I use it? What is it capable of in this situation? I'm asking so that I know what to learn

Comment: You can step through code a line at a time and inspect the state of variables and see the exact flow of the program interactively.  This link seems to be popular to pass around on here to teach people how to debug: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Note that you have both too many and too few parentheses in `#define right_child_index(i) (((i + 1) << 1))`.  You have too many because you don't need double-parentheses around the whole expression; you have too few because you don't have parentheses around `i`.  You need `#define right_child_index(i) (((i) + 1) << 1)`.  When working with macros for arithmetic, you need to enclose each argument in parentheses in the expansion to protect against misinterpretation.  Similar comments apply to the other macros.

Comment: Corrected, but the output is still the same (i know that it is a potential error that had to be corrected, but this was not the case)

Comment: link to [gdb manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/)

Comment: the `ddd` tool is built on top of `gdb` to provide a visual interface.  [ddd manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/manual/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(answering my own question)

The macro is_higher(a, b), was meant to represent the ordering. It should be (((a)>(b))? 1 : 0), i.e. it should be 1 (true) when a is greater than b, 0 (false) otherwise.

A pointer to function would have been a much better choice, since it is:

A) less error-prone

B) more flexible (it would be possible to change the ordering at runtime)

Comment: is_higher ((a)>(b)) would be sufficient.  it is already true or false.

Comment: Indeed, my answer was redundant